# PHP: Date intervall (weeks) only includes dates from current, and not previous, month

Tags: php

I have this small code segment that prints a date interval:

```
$week = strtotime("-1 week"); 
$basic = date('Y', strtotime("-1 week"));
$start = __('%s-%s', $basic, date('m-d', strtotime("monday this week", $week)));
$end = __('%s-%s', $basic, date('m-d', strtotime("sunday this week", $week)));
```

The code produces the follow output:

30.**08**.18 - 05.08.18

However, I want the code to give me the values from *last week* so it should be: 30.**07**.18 - 05.08.18

(Highlighted for readability).

I've tried several variations, such as changing the basic time from Y to M but without results. I have also looked at previous questions and solutions without resolving the issue.

Thanks in advance.

**Update** The error was in a different part of the system that handled time and file generation. The code in this post is correct.

Comment: What is `__()` ?

Comment: $today = date('Y-m-d');
$oneweekago=date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-7 days'));

echo $today . PHP_EOL . $oneweekago;

Comment: $week = strtotime("-1 week");
var_dump(date('d-m-Y',strtotime("monday this week", $week)).' - '.date('d-m-Y',strtotime("sunday this week", $week)));

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are wanting to `last` keyword, see  [Relative Formats Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) that kind of explains it. But mainly its a little trial and error.

```
php > echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 week'));
2018-08-01

php > echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of last week'));
2018-07-01

php > echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last week'));
2018-07-30
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments! The output is printed in a PDF. For some reason, the suggestions above did not help me solve the problem (did quite a lot of trial and error), but I might come a bit closer to understand the problem. I'll post the solution here when I solve it.

Thanks!